# Converting String to org.JSON does not maintain the order

Tags: java, json

I have a following JSON

```
"CustomError": {
                "ErrorDesc": "Method Not Allowed",
                "Error": "RaiseFault",
                "ErrorCode": "405"
              }
```

When I am converting it to JSONObject the order of the K-V are getting changed.

This is my piece of code

```
JSONObject policies = new JSONObject("\"CustomError\": {\n" +
                    "                \"ErrorDesc\": \"Method Not Allowed\",\n" +
                    "                \"Error\": \"RaiseFault\",\n" +
                    "                \"ErrorCode\": \"405\"\n" +
                    "              }");

policies.get("CustomError");
```

The returns the random order of K-V.
I know the org.JSON internally uses HashMap and not LinkedHashMap. But is there any way I can attain the order of K-V of my CustomError.

Comment: I have to compare this with other response JSON which has a custom error

Comment: Yes, I am using equals

Comment: Have you overriden it?

Comment: Try using `getJSONObject` instead of `get`

Comment: @Jaeheon getJSONObject also wont solve this issue. I already tried

Comment: @User I am not overriding. I am just just trying to get the JSONObject by getObject("customError) and compare it with the other reponse

Comment: How about deserializing both JSON responses into classes that implement equals() according to what you need (probably LinkedHashMap or TreeMap would work).